# implicit conversion loses integer precision 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber

Hi i am getting this error! i am using NSNumber in indexpath.row but it giving Warning,what is wrong in my code please help.

```
 NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];
        [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(callingMethod:) onTarget:self  withObject:num animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`indexPath.row` is returning `NSInteger` value not `int` value. Try this

```
NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use boxed expression. here how you can do :

```
NSNumber *num = @(indexPath.row]);
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(callingMethod:) onTarget:self  withObject:num animated:YES];
```

this will convert your number with the right format;

Let me know if this help you :)